# Launching an external application from within a NPAPI Plugin

Tags: winapi, plugins, shellexecute, npapi, createprocess

I am trying to work out why an NPAPI plugin I have written, which works fine in terms of performing operations triggered via Javascipt calls, cannot use CreateProcess() or ShellExecute() to launch an application from a path specified via the Javascript call.

I can seemingly use either of these methods and they return success, i.e. no error code. But the application just does not launch. I have tried modifying the parameters used when calling them, to create new process group etc. But seemingly with no effect.

I know this may seem like a bit of a security risk, but for the very specific purpose we wish to use it for it shouldn't be a problem.

Using Windows XP Pro SP3, Firefox 3.5 and the following code:

```
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) ); 
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) ); 
if( CreateProcess( NULL, wFileName, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                  CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, 
                  NULL, NULL, &si, &pi ) )
{ 
    bSuccess = true; // Close process and thread handles.      
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE); 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess ); 
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread ); 
}
```

Comment: What browser and windows version?

Comment: Windows XP Pro SP3 and Firefox 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code (snippet) to chew on it is really hard to give valuable hints:

I don't see why this should not work on XP.
Are you sure that the CreateProcess()/ShellExecute() calls succeed?

Things to try:

- Does the ShellExecute() call also succeed if you pass an invalid path?
- What happens if you use a hard-coded path (e.g. the path to notepad.exe, a path without spaces, etc.)?
- Check with ProcessMonitor (former filemon) if the executable file of the application you are trying to launch is acceessed.

Maybe the executable doesn't launch because a depending DLL is not found.
Keep in mind that the working/current directory is the directory of the browser executable when launching the application from within a plugin.
 
Therefore DLLs that are located in the application folder might not be found.

Comment: I have tried it with invalid paths and it definitely returns an error in that case, I have also tried as you suggested, just hardcoding it to open something like notepad, with no success.

I am also using absolute paths, so it shouldn't matter what directory the current directory is.

I'll take a look at process monitor just incase.

Thanks.

Comment: `depends.exe` worked wonders for me in some rare cases - using it in the trace mode for FF could give more information about failed system calls.

Comment: Tried running the same code in simple console app and it started the exe fine, seems to be something to do with trying to launch it from within a DLL?

Not sure how to use depends.exe to do what you say, could you provide steps to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Adam: *File->Open* and load firefox.exe, then *Profile->Start Profiling*, set the arguments so your test page is loaded right away, etc. ...